# About Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $(a_{2n-1})$ and $(a_{2n})$ has no Cauchy subsequence. Is it also true that $(a_n)$ has no Cauchy subsequence?

Let $A=\{a_{2n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, is it true every Cauchy sequence in $A$ is constant?

Answer (score 2):

True : If $b_n$ is a subsequence in $\{ a_n\}$ s.t. it is Cauchy,
then one of them $\{ a_{2n}\},\ \{ a_{2n-1}\}$ contains $b_n$
infinitely many. If $
 \{ a_{2n}\}$ contains a subsequence $\{ c_n\}$
 of $\{ b_n\}$ (Note that $c_n$ is a Cauchy), then contradiction.

Comment: I thought so. But I find it difficult to give formal proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KeyboardPersonal Use the fact that $\{a_{n_k}\}\subset \{a_{2n}\}\cup\{a_{2n+1}\}$ for any subsequence $(a_{n_k})$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Alright, I'll try.

What about second question? Any thought? Looks like it's not constant sequence, but it's tail is constant. In other words, there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=x_N$ for every $n \geq N$. But I can't prove or give counterexample.

Comment: @KeyboardPersonal Yes, I think this is correct. Assume there is a Cauchy sequence $(b_k)$ which does not have a constant tail. Then construct by induction a subsequence $(b_{k_m})$ which is also a subsequence of $(a_{2n})$, which gives a contradiction. If you don't know how, you should ask a new question about it.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I already create new question (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224744/cauchy-sequences-on-certain-set) about it. If you don't mind, you can help me again.