# Cauchy sequences on certain set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $(a_{n})$ has no Cauchy subsequence. Let $A=\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, is it true every Cauchy sequence $(b_n)$ in $A$ have a constant tail (In other words, there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n=b_N$ for every $n \geq N$)?

I asked this before (see [About Cauchy sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220748/about-cauchy-sequence/1220751)). However, I don't fully understand the answer and I was advised to ask a new question about it.

Comment: I see only one technical snag here. I can fairly easily prove that given a Cauchy sequence $b_n$ in $A$ which does not have a constant tail, there is a subsequence of $b_n$ which consists entirely of distinct values. This subsequence will also be Cauchy, since any subsequence of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy. But I am not sure how to ensure that this subsequence is a subsequence of the $a_n$, i.e. that its values necessarily appear in the proper order.

Comment: No. In $\mathbb{R}$, $\{ a_n= \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \}$ is a Cauchy. But it does not have constant tail.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee I think I make mistake. Sequence that have constant tail is sequence in $A$, not $a_n$ (already edited). $a_n$ is not Cauchy sequence because it does not have Cauchy subsequence..

Answer (score 1):

If $(b_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$, there are two possibilities. If $(b_n)$ takes only finitely many values, then it must have a constant tail (or else there would be distinct elements of $A$ which appear in $(b_n)$ infinitely many times, in which case they would both be limit points and so $(b_n)$ would not be Cuachy). The other possibility is that it takes infinitely many values. In this case, we can construct a subsequence of $(a_n)$ which is also a subsequence of $(b_n)$. We do this by setting $a_{n_1}=b_1$, then given $a_{n_1},\ldots,a_{n_k}$, we have so far only gone past finitely many elements of $(a_n)$, but there are infinitely many $b_n$, so we choose $a_{n_{k+1}}$ to be further along both sequences than anything we have passed thus far.

Since $(b_n)$ is Cauchy, all subsequences are Cauchy, so we have a Cauchy subsequence of $(a_n)$, a contradiction. Hence every Cauchy sequence in $A$ must have a constant tail.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand your way of construct subsequence. Can you explain it more how do construct it so it can lead contradiction?